# Was Koichi going to die if he hadn't been cured by Josuke?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In one of the earliest episodes of Diamond is unbreakable, Koichi is pierced by the arrow which awakens stand powers. He was badly injured, and Josuke stated he was going to die, so he cured him with his stand. However, Koichi awakened his stand, and it's said that few who are pierced by the arrow and survive, they awaken a stand.

So, was he supposedly going to die, or was he supposed to survive because he awakened a stand even though he was badly injured and unconscious?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately Koichi would have died from the arrow. Instances where the arrow grants people Stands results in an immediate reaction like with Angelo. Since Koichi was pierced and on the floor unconscious without any immediate change, it is safe to say he would've died if it wasn't for Josuke healing him in time.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, Koichi would have died without Josuke's intervention.

Keicho's comments after shooting Koichi suggest the Arrow is a "test" with two possible outcomes: if the user has a strong enough fighting spirit, they'll survive and acquire a Stand; otherwise, they'll die. Josuke healing Koichi with Crazy Diamond essentially forced what should have been a failure/death outcome into a success/survival outcome.

However, despite surviving the Arrow attack, Koichi's fighting spirit is still underdeveloped; he can't manifest his Stand by himself, and when Keicho forces the issue by attacking with Bad Company, the result is an immature Stand in the form of an egg. The audience is left to infer that the point where the egg hatches into Echoes represents Koichi reaching the minimum level of fighting spirit necessary to properly manifest and control a Stand.